# end if without block if, though if statements are closed

Tags: excel, vba

I'm getting a mysterious 'End If without block If' error in my vba 2013 code. Any insight on what's going wrong?

I get the error with both 'End If's. If I comment them out, it throws a 424 error at me on the second line of either of the 'If' blocks.

Code (in ThisWorkbook):

```
Sub TryAgain()

Dim ran As Range
Dim strt As Range
Dim X As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set strt = Sheet3.Range("A2")
Set ran = Sheet3.Range(strt, strt.End(xlDown))

n = 1

For Each blah In ran:

    cause = blah.Offset(0, 11)
    X = 0
    c = 0

    Do Until X = n:
        citem = Sheet4.Cells(1, 1).Offset(X, 0)

        If cause.Value = citem.Value Then:
            citem.Offset(0, 1).Value = citem.Offset(0, 1).Value + 1
            c = c + 1
        End If

        X = X + 1
    Loop

    If c = 0 Then:
        bernerner = Sheet4.Cells(1, 1).Offset(X, 0)
        bernerner.Offset(1, 0).Value = cause.Value
        bernerner.Offset(1, 1).Value = bernerner.Offset(1, 1).Value + 1
        n = n + 1
    End If
Next blah

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need `:` in VBA.

For , While and If none of these need a `:` at the end.